# URLSession webSocketTask is aborted after background mode

Tags: ios, swift, websocket, urlsession

In my project I have `URLSession.shared.webSocketTask(with: url)` to listen to incoming updates from the server. When I hide and open the app again (I guess enter background mode) the socket connection is aborted and I get following errors:

```
2023-02-17 16:50:58.147335+0100 App[6057:327579] [connection] nw_read_request_report [C2] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"
2023-02-17 16:50:58.147546+0100 App[6057:327579] [connection] nw_read_request_report [C1] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"
2023-02-17 16:50:58.149527+0100 App[6057:327578] [websocket] Read completed with an error Software caused connection abort
2023-02-17 16:50:58.150047+0100 App[6057:327578] Task <5BFFE42D-3DC8-4B1F-BFB9-8E7985D588DF>.<1> finished with error [53] Error Domain=kNWErrorDomainPOSIX Code=53 "Software caused connection abort" UserInfo={NSDescription=Software caused connection abort, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalWebSocketTask <5BFFE42D-3DC8-4B1F-BFB9-8E7985D588DF>.<1>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalWebSocketTask <5BFFE42D-3DC8-4B1F-BFB9-8E7985D588DF>.<1>}
2023-02-17 16:50:58.152318+0100 App[6057:327579] [connection] nw_flow_add_write_request [C1 18.66.192.38:443 failed parent-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0[802.11], ipv4, dns)] cannot accept write requests
2023-02-17 16:50:58.152392+0100 App[6057:327579] [connection] nw_write_request_report [C1] Send failed with error "Socket is not connected"
16:50:58 [LOG] error: Error Domain=kNWErrorDomainPOSIX Code=53 "Software caused connection abort" UserInfo={NSDescription=Software caused connection abort}
```

So it seems like the system drops my socket connections since the file system is not writeable anymore. I already tried some solutions from the internet like:

```
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
config.waitsForConnectivity = true
config.shouldUseExtendedBackgroundIdleMode = true
let session = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
```

but still have the same issue.
Using `URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "example")` also does not help, it crashes with an error: `WebSocket tasks are not supported in background sessions`.

I guess the only strait forward solution is just to request a new session after the error occurs. But I believe there is a better setup for that. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message explains iOS does not support Web socket sessions when the app is in the background.

You can register for a notification for when the app is returned to foreground and then reconnect your socket. e.g.:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationWillEnterForeground), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)

@objc func applicationWillEnterForeground() {
    resetSocketConnection()
}
```